# How can we restrict users from copying "non-allowed" file types from USB?

Tags: usb, file-system, data-validation, dlp, end-points

We blocked USB ports on most of the devices using Intune. However, a subset of users requires USB access due to their job scope which requires them to copy images from their cameras to their PCs. Is there a way we can restrict users from copying any other file formats other than images to the workstation from their USB ports?

If this can't be done, is there a secure way of allowing the users to copy files from a USB and make sure they can't execute them?

Comment: If your goal is to prevent users from introducing new executables onto your system, mount their removable media, home directory, and anywhere else they can write to as "noexec".  Just because a file IS a valid image doesn't mean it is not (or does not contain) a valid shell script or binary executable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)#Security_Implications

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, I don't think Intune has that feature. For your second question, you may apply the following device control policies:

- Set all removable media to be read-only
- Disallow program execution from removable media
- Restrict all devices from specific vendors
- Restrict specific devices identified by vendor ID, product ID, and serial number

See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/mac-device-control-intune?view=o365-worldwide)